# Are there any published studies on cases of infinite sums for which the Euler–Maclaurin summation method yields the exact evaluation?

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, integration

The Euler–Maclaurin summation formula is as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula): $$\sum_{i=m}^{n} f(i) = \int_{m}^{n} f(x) dx + \frac{f(n)+f(m)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2 \rfloor} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\big{(}f^{(2k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(m)\big{)} + R_{p} .$$

Usually, it yields an approximation, because the third term (the sum involving the Bernoulli numbers) and the remainder term cannot be evaluated exactly.

If the higher derivatives eventually become zero at the start and end points, the formula becomes exact. An example of an application of this fact is Faulhaber's formula.

However, Faulhaber's formula pertains to finite sums. I wonder whether there are infinite series for which all terms of the formula above *can* be evaluated. In particular, I would like to know whether some systematic study on the circumstances under which such an evaluation is possible and exact has been published.

I've asked a similar question [In what case(s) does the Euler-Maclaurin summation method yield the exact evaluation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188562/in-what-cases-does-the-euler-maclaurin-summation-method-yield-the-exact-evalua) a while ago on MSE.

---

*Added note*. To clarify, by ‘exact’ I mean ‘has a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) expression’.

Comment: (i) "the third term (the sum involving the Bernoulli numbers) and the remainder term cannot be evaluated exactly". Why (in what sense) can't the sum involving the Bernoulli numbers be evaluated exactly? (ii) "If the higher derivatives eventually become zero at the start and end points, the formula becomes exact." Exact in what sense, exactly?

Comment: (iii) "I wonder whether there are infinite series for which all terms of the formula above can be evaluated." What infinite series? (You only have a finite sum in your post.) Also, what do you mean, exactly, by "all terms of the formula" and, again, by "can be evaluated"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis (i) Please note I said it *usually* can't be evaluated exactly. By an exact evaluation, I mean something like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} $ and many others, like the ones listed over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)

Comment: (ii) It becomes exact in the sense that it isn't an approximation, and yields the correct answer for any sum of powers. (iii) I mean *any* convergent infinite series. I'm not looking for a specific one, but for any evaluation of an infinite series by means of the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. As for an evaluation of the terms (there are four in the formula, and three if one can show that $R_{p}$ tends to zero for $n \to \infty$), please refer to my answer to (i)

Comment: (In the comment above, I meant $p \to \infty$ instead of $n \to \infty$ )

Comment: I would also consider 'closed-form' a synonym of 'exact' in this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: One should mention here that for many usual functions $f$ and for fixed $m,n$, the error term $R_p$ does not converge to 0 when $p \to \infty$. Euler-Maclaurin provides an asymptotic expansion, but it does not always converge.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this answer your question, but it is an approximation. It is not a reference, only that
many years ago I wrote for my use an exposition of  Euler-MacLaurin's formula.
Defining first the Bernoulli polynomials so that I can use them in successive integrations by parts. I arrived to the expression (with $a$ and $b$ integers)
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{j=a}^bf(j)=\int_a^bf(x)\,dx+\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\\+\sum_{j=2}^n(-1)^j\frac{B_j}{j!}\bigl(f^{(j-1)}(b)-f^{(j-1)}(a)\bigr)+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\int_a^bf^{(n)}(x)\widetilde{B}_n(x)\,dx.
\end{multline*}
To determine the Bernoulli numbers, I proposed to apply the above to $f(x)=e^{-hx}$ with $h>0$; let $a=0$ and $b=m$. Then $f^{(j)}(x)=(-h)^je^{-hx}$, The right hand side is a geometrical series with sum
$$\sum_{j=0}^m e^{-hj} =\frac{1-e^{-(m+1)h}}{1-e^{-h}}.$$
Hence our equality is in this case
\begin{multline*}
\frac{1-e^{-(m+1)h}}{1-e^{-h}}=\frac{1-e^{-mh}}{h}+\frac{1+e^{-mh}}{2}\\+
\sum_{j=2}^n(-1)^j\frac{B_j}{j!}\bigl[(-h)^{j-1}e^{-mh}-(-1)^{j-1}\bigr]
+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^m(-h)^ne^{-hx}\widetilde{B}_n(x)\,dx.
\end{multline*}
Multiplying by $h$ and simplifying yields
$$\frac{h}{1-e^{-h}}(1-e^{-(m+1)h})=\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{B_j}{j!}h^j\Bigr)(1-e^{-mh})-\frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^m e^{-hx}\widetilde{B}_n(x).$$
Since $h>0$ we may take limits when $m\to+\infty$ and we get
$$\frac{h}{1-e^{-h}}=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{B_j}{j!}h^j-\frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^m e^{-hx}\widetilde{B}_n(x).$$
So that for each $n$ there is a constant $C_n$ such that for $0<h<1$
$$\Bigl|\frac{h}{1-e^{-h}}-\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{B_j}{j!}h^j\Bigr|\le C_nh^{n+1}.$$
It follows that $x/(1-e^{-x})$ have a Taylor series
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{B_j}{j!}x^j.$$
This can be thought as an exact MacLaurin evaluation with $n=\infty$.

Comment: Hi @juan, thank you for your answer. Indeed it isn't entirely what I'm looking for - but I think the nice exposition you gave above would be one good entry (out of many) of examples in the overview article I'm seeking